# Script doesn't work in Bootstrap 4 Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I added a scroll to top script to my website (developed with Bootstrap 4) and it doesn't work. However this script works on the same website which was developed with Bootstrap 3. I think that there's an error occurred with bootstrap version, but unfortunately I can't find the issue.

```html
<div class="toTop">
    <a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-up icons"></i></a>
</div>
```

```js
$('.toTop').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Console log:

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
smooth.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at smooth.js:2
(anonymous) @ smooth.js:2
```

That's a Wordpress website with a theme, developed with Bootstrap 4.

jQuery loads from finctions.php via:

```
// include custom jQuery
function shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery');
```

Comment: remove dollar and try keeping `jQuery.(".toTop")`...

Comment: @MadhuNair unfortunately nothing happened

Comment: try some alternative jquery include

Comment: I've tried but that didn't help

Comment: Why are you `deregister`ing the script first? Where is your smooth scroll script registered?

Comment: I've registered the script in my footer.php

Comment: Is that the only jQuery script failing?

Comment: yep, only this script fails